# How to set the base path for the java doc

Tags: java, spring, javadoc

I have a spring application and I am building the javadoc.

I use [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to test it:

```
npm install -g serve
# in javadoc folder
serve
```

It work fine when I test it locally under `http://localhost:5000`.

I want now to expose it under a different folder `/javadoc`, I move the whole content in this directory and try again.

`http://localhost:5000/javadoc`.

When I access the website I have the following error:

[image]

How can I set a base path to the java doc during the Java doc build?

It seems that these line can be manually fix, but that is not satisfying:

```
- <frame src="overview-frame.html" name="packageListFrame" title="All Packages">
+ <frame src="javadoc/overview-frame.html" name="packageListFrame" title="All Packages">
- <frame src="allclasses-frame.html" name="packageFrame" title="All classes and interfaces (except non-static nested types)">
+ <frame src="javadoc/allclasses-frame.html" name="packageFrame" title="All classes and interfaces (except non-static nested types)">
- <frame src="overview-summary.html" name="classFrame" title="Package, class and interface descriptions" scrolling="yes">
+ <frame src="javadoc/overview-summary.html" name="classFrame" title="Package, class and interface descriptions" scrolling="yes">
```

Comment: provide local URL, and deployed URL?

Comment: When you generate javadoc, the resulting files are in a folder. There should be an index.html file in there. Make sure that file knows how to find its brothers on your server.

Comment: @dylan this is the index.html, but I have 3 `<frame src="some-file.html" />` in it, and they are trying to access from the base path, as soon as I prefix them with `javadoc/`  it can work again. Any idea?

Comment: @ahmednabil88 just did it